# Hide image in smarty array

Tags: html, smarty

I've built a website using CMS Made Simple and it uses alot of smarty templating within it's modules.  There is a catalogue module which I am using which I need some help with.

I need to hide the very first image in the array (in both the thumbnail and the larger version).  Can anyone help with providing a solution which would get this to work.

This is the smarty template for the page which displays thumbnails and a large version of each thumb image.

This is the sample of smarty and html which handles the array in my template:

```
<div class="item_thumbnails">
{section name=ind loop=$image_url_array}

<a href="{$image_url_array[ind]}" rel="zoom-id:zoom" rev="{$image_url_array[ind]}">
<img src="{$image_thumb_url_array[ind]}" title="{$title}" alt="{$title}" /></a>{/section}

</div>
```

Here's the full code in jsfiddle [template code](http://jsfiddle.net/2CGeS/)

and this is how the page is seen on the front end: http://www.intricatecreations.co.uk/index.php?page=cascading-flowers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "hide" you mean hiding with css or removing it from the html output?

In any case, you should use $smarty.section.ind.first:

remove:

```
{section name=ind loop=$image_url_array}
{if !$smarty.section.ind.first}
<a href="{$image_url_array[ind]}" rel="zoom-id:zoom" rev="{$image_url_array[ind]}">
<img src="{$image_thumb_url_array[ind]}" title="{$title}" alt="{$title}" />
</a>
{/if}
{/section}
```

hide:

```
{section name=ind loop=$image_url_array}
<a href="{$image_url_array[ind]}" rel="zoom-id:zoom" rev="{$image_url_array[ind]}" {if $smarty.section.ind.first}style="display:none"{/if}>
<img src="{$image_thumb_url_array[ind]}" title="{$title}" alt="{$title}" />
</a>
{/if}
{/section}
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you. This has removed the first thumbnail. How would I go about removing and or hiding the first larger image?

Comment: Removing the big image would involve some php or javascript modifications, as you cannot simply remove the tag. A workaround would be replacing {$image_1_url} with an empty/transparent image (i.e. blank.png). Also, have you tried to just remove the first image from the array with php's array_shift before sending it to smarty?

Comment: I see what you mean however I'm not very familiar with php so I wouldn't know where to look to try this.